# How to take the sum of a index within a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

For school I'm working on a project where i need to make a programm in python, but i'm stuck at this point for a long time now.

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(items):
    ar.append([])
    ar[i].append(int(input('Aantal ' + item + ' consumpties' + ': ')))
    ar[i].append(float(input('Inkoop prijs ' + item + ' : ')))
    ar[i].append(float(input('Inhoud verpakking: ')))
    ar[i].append(float(input('Hoeveel liter drank gaat er in een beker / hoeveelste deel word uitgegegeven? ')))

for (i, item) in enumerate(items):
    ar[i].append(math.floor(ar[i][2] / ar[i][3]))
    print(ar[i][4])
    ar[i].append(math.ceil(ar[i][0] / ar[i][4]))
    print(ar[i][5])
```

So I'm appending some values into a list and I need to know how I can get all `[i][5]` indexes and take the sum of that (into a variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple generator expression passed to `sum` will do what you want.

```
my_sum = sum(item[5] for item in ar)
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero :)